# No prompt appears when I fire up the IPython Console

Tags: ipython, prompt

I am new to Linux and Python, just starting some programming this weekend. All was going great until this morning, when I was playing with "save" to save my workspace. (I selected the "magic" menu bar, so perhaps I screwed up something from there.) I must have changed my settings so that the prompt no longer appears when I start IPython. I get all the stuff that normally appears prior to getting the prompt (shown below), but no prompt and the interpreter does not work. If I run IPython in terminal, I get the prompt and all works fine. The problem is just in IPython console. I have rebooted just in case (perhaps this is a windows thing and does not apply to Linux).

Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:20:15)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

```
IPython 0.12.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
? -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help -> Python's own help system.
object? -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
%guiref -> A brief reference about the graphical user interface.
```

Answer (score 0):

"ipython console" or "ipython qtconsole" ? Also try upgrading, 0.12.1 is almost 2 years old.
You can try to remove/rename `~/.ipython` folder where all IPython config/history is stored.

Comment: Thank's for the response.  Yes, it is ipython qt console.  I updated to 0.13.2 and I still have the same problem.  I am embarrassed to ask about the location of the .ipython folder that has the configuration files.  I looked all around and could not find that folder.  Any hints of where a newbie like me can look for this folder.

Comment: `$ ipython locate` should tell you where it is. be careful file starting with dot are hidden and need `$ls -a` to be shown. `~` is the character that refer to your home. So for you `~` is probably `/home/<username>`, so `/home/mark`. Hence ipython config dir should be `/home/mark/.ipython`.

Comment: As you suggested, I changed the file ipython to ipython2.  I then ran ipython again, and the problem persists.  Note that a new ipython appeared in the configuration directory as you would expect.